# how to request API and send it to front

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, routes

I am new to node.js and I want to practice. I found this [example](https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/rest-countries-api-with-color-theme-switcher-5cacc469fec04111f7b848ca).

I made the home page good [home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWXmr.jpg) but when I click any country I can't display its information, I mean I can request the data for the country I clicked but I can't send it to the page that I rendered to display these information
I want it looks like this 
[countryinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shdpy.jpg)

this is the node

```
    const express = require("express")
    const app = express()
    const https = require("https")
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    app.set("view engine", "ejs")
    app.use(express.static("./public"))
    var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
    app.get("/" , (req, res) =>{
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
    })

    app.get("/:thename" , (req, res) =>{
        res.render("countryinfo")

    })
    app.post("/:thename" , urlencodedParser,(req, res) =>{
        let theName = `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${req.params.thename}`;
        https.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${req.params.thename}`, (resp) => {
        let data = '';

        // A chunk of data has been recieved.
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
          data += chunk;
        });

        // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
        resp.on('end', () => {
          res.json(JSON.parse(data));
        });
     })
app.listen("3000")
```

and this is the javascript file

```
countries.forEach(nation=>{
    nation.addEventListener("click", getInfo)
    function getInfo () {
        var theName = nation.children[0].getAttribute("href")
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: theName,
            success: function(){

            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: theName,
            data: {name: theName},
            success: function(data){//updated data
            }
        });
    }
})
```

what I should do to send data to rendered page?
this how my directories looks like: [directories](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-fast-ml4mp)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to update your front in the success function where data has been received.

Comment: That is what I can't do